# Swift pasted from iBooks into Xcode playground doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm learning Swift from the Apple Swift book on iBooks, and code pasted into an Xcode playground from the book does not work. The code needs to be completely re-typed to work. Is there any way around this?

[image]

Comment: You're probably getting evil invisibles in the copied code. Try pasting into a text editor, copying, and pasting into the playground.

Comment: Even better, use the version in the Xcode docs, which lets you run directly.

Comment: If you click on the red buttons at the left of the code, what does it propose you to do to fix this ?

Comment: matt - Yea, I've tried the text editor thing. Doesn't work. I've played with the Xcode docs version, but I'd generally like to be able to do this because there are other swift books on iBooks as well.

Kevin - It asks me to insert a `;` which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: I for one appreciate this question and do not find it off topic at all. It is tagged appropriately. It has all the proper Google-fu to help people like me find it. It addresses an issue that a developer will encounter if they go to the authoritative source for documentation on a new programming language. I actually believed that Apple's compile as you type was freaking out at the speed of a code paste. I've had remote terminals do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @matt commented, you're better off working from the Xcode documentation window or the HTML version of the book in a web browser. iBooks, despite being an electronic medium, uses a lot of formatting tricks from the print publishing world that put invisible, illegal-for-Swift characters in the text.

You can find the web version of [*The Swift Programming Language* on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-XID_0). Ditto for the other Apple Swift iBook, [*Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html), and a lot of other documentation (Swift-specific and otherwise) that isn't on iBooks. You can copy-paste from the web version of the docs without getting invisible garbage characters.

You can also download the first chapter in [TSPL, "A Swift Tour"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-XID_0), as a runnable playground, so for that you can save the copy-pasting/typing entirely.
[image]

---

The command `less` by default will show you special characters. You can pipe the output of `pbpaste` to `less` to see true state of your clipboard. (The option -X prevents the screen from clearing which is good for capturing shell transcripts.)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll be copying soft returns from the book instead of proper line endings. In the text editor, turn on invisible characters, and look at the difference between the line ending character and the one that appears when you press return.

iBooks does nasty things when you copy-paste (adding attribution, for example) so it's not great for copying code from.